# Android View (Dialog / Layout) across multiple Activities

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-linearlayout, android-windowmanager

I've created a view that I want to use as an error message.

If the phone has no internet connection (mobile data or wifi), I want to show an error message within my app so user knows that everything from that point on, will be locally saved (not on the server).

The problem here is that I want this message to stay up even when user goes from one activity to another.

I tried using a Dialog and LinearLayout on WindowManager.
Didn't work.

This is what I did.

```
    public void noConnectionLayout()
    {
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout (this.ApplicationContext);
        mainLayout.Clickable = false;
        mainLayout.Focusable = false;
        mainLayout.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        mainLayout.LongClickable = false;
        mainLayout.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        mainLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        var spaceFromTopPara = (int) (65 * this.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        var layoutHeight = (int)(25 * this.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

        WindowManagerLayoutParams windowLayoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams (
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
            layoutHeight,
            WindowManagerTypes.SystemError, 
            WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal | WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable, 
            Format.Translucent);
        windowLayoutParams.ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        windowLayoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
        windowLayoutParams.Y = spaceFromTopPara;

        TextView textNoConnectionMesg = new TextView (this);
        textNoConnectionMesg.Text = "No Connection available.";
        textNoConnectionMesg.SetTypeface (this.latoFont, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        textNoConnectionMesg.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        textNoConnectionMesg.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        textNoConnectionMesg.SetTextSize (Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 14f);
        textNoConnectionMesg.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        textNoConnectionMesg.SetTextColor (Android.Graphics.Color.White);

        mainLayout.AddView (textNoConnectionMesg);

        WindowManager.AddView (mainLayout, windowLayoutParams);

    }
```

When the activity changes, the view just goes away.

What can I do here?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: One way would be to pass the message to the new activity and recreate the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs are inherently associated with Activities. It seems odd that your users would even be able to navigate between Activities with a dialog showing. If you want to allow navigation **and** have the connection status dialog be displayed on each screen, you'll need to show the Dialog in e.g. the onStart of a BaseActivity that all your other Activities extend.

Comment: So basically I have to create a new `Activity`, call my above function in `OnStart` and extend all my other activities to that activity? That's a really good idea but How I would remove that View when the connection is back?

Comment: You can listen for changes in connectivity as [described in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges). When connectivity changes, you can query its state and then respond accordingly. Refer to documentation and other SO answers for this - it's not entirely trivial, since you need to determine whether your application is in the foreground when the broadcast is received, for example.